# C++ palindrome not working

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, if-statement

I wanted to create function that returns true/false according if the input is a palindrome or not, when  given abcddcba or aba it does not give true, but it should . plz help

```
bool checkPalindrome(char input[],int p=0) {
    if(input[1]=='\0'){
        return true;
    }
    if(sizeof(input)%2==0) { 
        int a = sizeof(input); 
        for(int i=0;i<(a/2);i++) {  
            if(input[0+i]==input[a-i-2]){
                p++;
            }
        }
        if(p==a/2){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        int a = sizeof(input); 
        for(int i=0;i<((a-1)/2);i++)
        {
            if(input[0+i]==input[a-i-2]){
                p++;
            }
        }
        if(p==(a-1)/2){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you never have used a debugger before, now is the perfect time to learn how to use one. With a debugger you can step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: `sizeof(input)` will return `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < S.size() / 2; i++) {
      if (S[i] != S[S.size() - 1 - i]) {
             return false;
      }
}

return true;

Comment: A small hint about a possible source for your problem though: The variable `input` is a *pointer*, and getting the `sizeof` of a pointer returns the size *of the pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: @SemyonBurov No, it will most likely be `4` or `8`, depending on if the OP is on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oops, my bad. I mean not the size of array.

Comment: You have to use `strlen()` to get the length of a string, not `sizeof`. But you should use `std::string` instead of C strings.

Answer (score 3):

C++ style:

```
bool checkPalindrome(const std::string& str)
{
    size_t len = str.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != str[len-1-i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

C style:

```
bool checkPalindrome(const char* str)
{
    size_t len = str ? strlen(str) : 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != str[len-1-i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In either case, you may need to evaluate (ask) if an empty string should be considered a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 1):

your code is too long. There's a simple way: iterating once over the elements of the string comparing the n-1 with 0 and n-2 with 1 and so on.

If two characters are not identical return false otherwise continue checking:

```
bool checkPalindrome(char* str) {
    const int size = strlen(str);
    for(int i(0), j(size) - 1); i < size / 2; i++, j--)
        if(str[i] != str[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(){

    char* str = "level";
    cout << checkPalindrome(str);

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You incur a performance penalty for invoking `strlen` on every iteration of the for loop.  You also do twice as many comparisons as necessary.

Comment: Nice ! But if this is a C++ question, and if we are in 2017, can someone explain why we are not using `string` but still `char*`  ?

Comment: @Christophe: Using string is too much safer and easier but I kept only the codes of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

C++ version based on strings and iterators (only for the sake of completeness, the other answers are already very nice) :

```
bool checkPalindrome(const string& str) {
    for (auto p = str.begin(),q = str.end();  p!=q && p!=q+1; p++ ) 
        if (*p!=*--q)       // if char from front doesn't match char from rear ?
            return false;   // then it's not a palindrome !
    return true;
}
```

***Explanations:*** the iterator `p` starts at the front of the string and `q` at the rear (after the last char).  `p` will advance and `q` will go backwards.  If `p` reaches `q` or if `p` has passed `q` (special case if the word has an even length), it's over and we can conclude a palindrome. But if before, there is any difference between the char at `p` and the char preceeding `q` , it's not a palindrome.

[Online demo, with little test suite](https://ideone.com/30Aufy)